# Angular throttle method called by class-binding [class.something]="methodCalled()"

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using class-binding to apply class to a div inside ng-template like this,

```
<div #mobileTrialSection class="mobile-trial-section hidden-lg hidden-xl" [class.is-touching]="utils.isTouching( mobileTrialSection, null, 100 )">
    <div class="heading">Your trial. Free and easy.</div>
    <ul class="features">
        <li>Full access for 14 days</li>
        <li>No credit card required</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The class I am binding is **is-touching**,

This method **(isTouching)** is called like hundereds of times which I don't like because it can cause performance issues, I want to throttle this by **200ms**.

The method is as following:

```
isTouching( dynamicDiv: HTMLElement, referenceDiv: HTMLElement, offset: number = 0, className = 'is-touching', refSelector = null ): boolean {     
  if (!referenceDiv) {                                                                                                                           
    if (refSelector) {                                                                                                                         
        referenceDiv = document.querySelector(refSelector);                                                                                    
    } else {                                                                                                                                   
        referenceDiv = dynamicDiv.parentElement.previousElementSibling as HTMLElement;                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                               
  if ( !dynamicDiv.classList.contains( className ) ) {                                                                                           
    return ( dynamicDiv?.getBoundingClientRect().top - referenceDiv?.getBoundingClientRect().bottom ) < offset;                                
  }                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                               
  return ( window.innerHeight - dynamicDiv?.offsetTop - dynamicDiv?.offsetHeight ) < offset;                                                     
}
```

Besides the logic, is there any other (better) way to bind class so using method so that it does not affect performance.

**NOTE:** In different scenarios where I want to throttle methods, I use pipes but this case is different and I don't know how to throttle such scenario. Constructive critisim would be appricieated.

Comment: You might wanna check out this thread about why **[it's not such a good idea to use method calls in property binding syntax in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069496/2622292)**.

Comment: ok thanks, I am gonna check this!

Comment: Thanks man, It helped a lot, I created my own solution but your answer helped me it.