# Dynamic form input validation using angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created dynamic form inputs in angular11. need to validate the form fields which added dynamically by clicking add button. i couldnt found the right solutions. here is my code

in component.ts file

```
this.pollAdd = this.fb.group({
      question: ['',Validators.required],
      queChoices:this.fb.array([this.createChoice()]),
    });

addChoice(){
    this.queChoices=this.pollAdd.get('queChoices') as FormArray;
    this.queChoices.push(this.createChoice());
  }

  createChoice():FormGroup{
    return this.fb.group({
      choice:['',Validators.required],
    })
  }

get f() { return this.pollAdd.controls; }
```

In component.html file

```
<div formArrayName="queChoices" *ngFor="let choices of pollAdd.get('queChoices')['controls'];let i=index;">
        <mat-form-field class="ch__custom_input w-100 mt-3" [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-label>Choice {{i+1}}</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="choice" autofocus/>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

how to validate each choice field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular FormArray display validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122433/angular-formarray-display-validation-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Get the name and check if there is an error, just like a regular form.

```
<div *ngIf="choice.errors?.required">Choice is required</div>
```

Comment: its showing console error  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

Comment: You can't just blindly copy and paste code from the answer.

Comment: yes i have tried but its showing errors undefined error

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="choices.controls['choice'].errors && choices.controls['choice'].touched">
            <mat-error *ngIf="choices.controls['choice'].errors?.required">Choice {{i+1}} is required!</mat-error>
          </div>
```

Its working for me...

Comment: using `mat-error`, if you has only an unique error, you needn't use *ngIf

Answer (score 0):

using mat-error, if we only has an unique error, we needn't use *ngIf, so is simply

```html
    <mat-error>required</mat-error>
```

We also use a function like

```
  getErrorMessage(inputRef:MatFormField) {
    const control=inputRef._control?inputRef._control.ngControl:null;
    if (!control || !control.errors)
      return null;
    if (control.hasError('required')) {
      return 'You must enter a value';
    }

    return control.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' : '';
  }
```

And pass the mat-field to the function getErrorMessage using a template reference variable

```html
      <mat-form-field #inputRef appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
        <input  matInput placeholder="pat@example.com" [formControl]="email" required>
        <mat-error  >{{getErrorMessage(inputRef)}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```